# Replace another element content with hovered element content

Tags: javascript, html, hover, clone

I am making a periodic table of elements, and would like the content of the smaller elements to appear in the bigger element on hover. Here is an image as an example:

[image]

Is there a fairly simple way to do this with plain javascript?

My code structure for the smaller elements would be similar to the following:

```html
<li class="element">
  <ul class="elec-state">
    <li>2</li>
  </ul>
  <span class="number">2</span>
  <h2 class="abv">He</h2>
  <h4 class="name">Helium</h4>
  <span class="weight">4.003</span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// Find all elements
document.querySelectorAll('.element').forEach(node => {
  // Add event listener for each element
  node.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {

    // Plain copy the html of the element
    let html = this.innerHTML

    // Fill canvas with elements html
    document.querySelector('#canvas').innerHTML = html
  })
})
```

```html
<button id="canvas"></button>
<br>
<button class="element"><span class="abv">One</span></button>
<button class="element"><span class="abv">Two</span></button>
<button class="element"><span class="abv">Three</span></button>
```

Comment: My apologies for not being more clear. I would need multiple pieces of content sent to '#canvas'. I've updated my original image, to match.

Comment: @user3450906 I've updated my answer. Note that this solution is really simple if you intend to have the same html structure in the *canvas* and each *element*. It gets more complex if they have different structures since you then would have to map each element attribute to the canvas attribute.

Comment: Awesome, this works great. And yes, they have the exact same structure.

Comment: By the way, I noticed this method does not work with IE. I think it is because IE does not support forEach with a nodelist, which is what querySelectorAll returns.